# Button not enabling/disabling when textfield has integer in it

Tags: swift, button, uitextfield

I am trying to activate a "convert" button once a user has inputted an integer value into a textfield labeled "Fahrenheit." I am having trouble gettting the text field to activate once integers are typed in the text field. Please see my code below for reference

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Fahrenheit.becomeFirstResponder()
    Convert.enabled = false
    Fahrenheit.delegate = self
    Fahrenheit.keyboardType = .DecimalPad

    if Int(Fahrenheit.text!) != nil{
        Convert.enabled = true
    }else{
        Convert.enabled = false

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [`textField(textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:) from `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and check if textField contains any text:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
  let currentText = NSString(string: textField.text ?? "")
  let newText = currentText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

  convertButton.enabled = !newText.isEmpty
  return true
}
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you are sure that the user won't press the button as long as text field is the first responder, you can do the above check in `textFieldDidEndEditing(textField:)` as well:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
  convertButton.enabled = textField.text?.isEmpty ?? false
}
```

You can play around with the [test project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xmgxlwcab59j258/AAAuzVFjFKSszG4USZUS9VvIa?dl=0) I created.